How is the universe able to run physics so smoothly?
Motivated by the discussion on whether chemistry can be reduced to physics, I came across a similar thread on Reddit, where a user commented:

A lot of chemistry has been reduced to physics, in the sense that you can perform long, expensive quantum mechanical simulations to reproduce chemical processes. This is called quantum chemistry or physical chemistry.
But much of chemistry necessarily involves a lot of atoms/molecules, and a lot of time-steps, before the phenomena become statistically significant (e.g. something involving small changes in pH). It's already a lengthy process to simulate just a few picoseconds of a dozen atoms interacting, and the difficulty scales exponentially with the number of particles (a little bit less with good approximations, but the point stands).
Quantum computers may help a little bit in the coming decades.
Chemical experiments and the laws of chemistry are time-tested and practical - we have given physical explanations for some of them, and probably would for the rest as well if it was possible to perform simulations at that level. But for now, for 99% of chemistry, it's not practical or useful to reduce it to physics.

From gazillions of atoms to complex molecules and biological systems, star systems, galaxies, and more, the universe essentially runs an advanced "simulation" of quantum mechanics, general relativity, and more—smoothly and seamlessly, without any apparent glitches. This makes me wonder: if simulating even a few atoms using the fundamental laws of quantum mechanics is computationally overwhelming, how does the universe manage to operate on such a vast scale?

EDITORIAL NOTE: originally I used  the word "bug", but it led to misunderstandings, so it was finally replaced with the word "glitch." For a discussion on the conceptual difference between "glitch" and "bug" see this thread on Reddit.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

You ask:

how does the universe manage to operate on such a vast scale?

Nomological constraints are not lines of software that execute. Under the current notions of physicalism (SEP), scientific laws (and that's not a term that has much currency these days) are descriptions of observed regularities, not edicts that some super intelligence has programmed into the universe. From the article:

Physicalism is, in slogan form, the thesis that everything is physical. The thesis is usually intended as a metaphysical thesis, parallel to the thesis attributed to the ancient Greek philosopher Thales, that everything is water, or the idealism of the 18th Century philosopher Berkeley, that everything is mental. The general idea is that the nature of the actual world (i.e. the universe and everything in it) conforms to a certain condition, the condition of being physical. Of course, physicalists don’t deny that the world might contain many items that at first glance don’t seem physical — items of a biological, or psychological, or moral, or social, or mathematical nature. But they insist nevertheless that at the end of the day such items are physical, or at least bear an important relation to the physical.

Thus, it is common for those who practice modern science to adopt the presumed metaphysical thesis that the universe is only physical stuff in the sense of matter and energy, or things that reduce to matter and energy, often called supervenience (SEP). Eliminative materialists insist that mental things don't really exist, and property dualists prefer to think of mental things as being properties of physical substances. But in all of these cases, the various sciences, which might best described as a collection of naturalized epistemologies (SEP) largely are the beliefs of physicalists such as cosmologists to describe how the universe is organized. Under these views, there is no physical evidence the universe is a simulation, though it makes for good science fiction and philosophical discourse.
There are those, like Seth Lloyd who advocate the view that the universe is computed (Edge.org) and have written books about it, and those like John Archibald Wheeler and his Participatory Anthropic Principle who push ideas that information is more fundamental than physical substances. This is often expressed as "it from bit", suggesting that physical substances are fundamentally information in composition. But these views go against modern thinking with regards to the relationship between information, computation, and physical systems (SEP). Computers are seen as abstraction of physical media.
Thus, you raise a great challenge to the simulation hypothesis. It seems overwhelming to imagine what sort of computer would be required to simulate even small sections of the physical universe, an object Daniel Dennett has raised a number of times himself in works like Consciousness Explained. Thus, the modern view is that "Laws of Science" are just descriptions of how physical substances behave, and do not determine the behavior. Some characterize the latter line of thinking "mistaking the map for the territory" or call it the reification fallacy. To wit, from WP:

Reification (also known as concretism, hypostatization, or the fallacy of misplaced concreteness) is a fallacy of ambiguity, when an abstraction (abstract belief or hypothetical construct) is treated as if it were a concrete real event or physical entity.


"Thus, you raise a great challenge to the simulation hypothesis. It seems overwhelming to imagine what sort of computer would be required to simulate even small sections of the physical universe" - With all due respect, I think you forgot about: shortcuts, screenshots, templates. One Sony PlayStation would be enough to convince you about the incredible complexity of the physical world (when you don't have references to compare).

@TheMatrixEquation-balance Uh, I think you misunderstood. The implicit assumption is that the simulation would have to be good enough to mistake it for the physical universe itself. I know of none who has played a game console and walked away clueless that it was a simulation. Dennett's argument about the permutation explosion required to do so still stands.

It is impossible for this to raise a challenge to the simulation hypothesis since the properties of the simulation tell us nothing about the world the simulation itself operates in.

@JackAidley Interesting riposte, however, scientific thinking dictates that claims of worlds beyond our current universe, simulation or not, require evidential support by some physical evidence in this universe. If you claim that such a speculative world exists, but that we cannot have evidence in this world since the "properties of this world" don't tell us of the next, then the claim, no matter how imaginative, is not a scientific claim and can neither be verified nor falsified. Isn't the term for that simply fiction?

@JD As far as I know there is no evidence that we live in a simulation, but if there were it would also be proof that the actual nature of reality outside the simulation is beyond that which scientific inquiry can determine.

Whether we live in a simulation is indeed not a testable hypothesis and not amenable to the scientific method. Nevertheless, the complexity of this world is no challenge to the idea. For all we know, the level of detail we can detect in the world around us is the equivalent of 8-bit color pixelated animations when compared to the full depth of detail in the postulated real world. It's just that this is a pointless rabbit hole to disappear into as none of it is testable.

"Isn't the term for that simply fiction?"  If the math backs it up (like possibly for the misnamed String Theory), then it's called a hypothesis, not fiction.

@RonJohn A hypothesis must be testable, and I'm not convinced that string theory meets that challenge. But point taken.

String theory is not really an apt comparison. However interesting string theory might be from a mathematical perspective, the goal (of physics and technology, at least) is to produce testable hypotheses. We're not there yet and may never reach it, which is why string theory cannot now be called "science". But I see utterly no coherent effort or proposal at producing a testable hypothesis for whether we live in a simulation.

"Thus, modern science has the presumed metaphysical thesis that the universe is only physical stuff in the sense of matter and energy, or things that reduce to matter and energy" -- no, not at all.  Such a view is reasonably popular among modern scientists, but it is not required for using the scientific method to construct and test scientific models, and it is not a presumption of "science".

@JohnBollinger Would you still protest if I substituted "methodological naturalism" for "modern science" in that sentence?

Yes, I would.  Methodological naturalism acknowledges, roughly speaking, that that the tools we have at our disposal serve scientific study only of the physical world, but it does not presume that there isn't anything else.

@JohnBollinger Fine. :P I concede. "Thus, it is common for those who practice modern science to adopt the presumed metaphysical thesis..." Thanks for the push back.

There is no indication that simulation needs to happen in real-time. One second for us could take 10^32 years to render and we would never know.

Relevant XKCD :)

There is no good reason for 10^32... 2^32 seems much more reasonable ;-). Otherwise, salient point.

People have probably created a CPU out of minecraft redstone by now. Doesn't run as fast as the machine it's running on, but I guess it still computes an addition within a single clock cycle...

Or the other way around: Our "real time" is just the computing/render speed of the universe. ;-)

@cmaster-reinstatemonica I know of this one, but I think there are even more sophisticated ones out there now.

@yshavit Nice when he runs Conway's Game of Life on it... :-)

@cmaster-reinstatemonica If you zoom in really carefully, you can see the cells posting on their philosphy.stackexchange.com asking how the universe computes things so quickly. :-D

One thing I think that XKCD missed is needing infinite wisdom to be able to make sense of infinite complexity in designing a ridiculously complex computer. I’m not at all convinced that humans with infinite time and resources could do that. As a programmer I can attest that we have a limit to how much complexity we can hold onto at once, and beyond a certain limit “page switching” out chunks of a system in our working memory isn’t sufficient to keep a working mental model of the whole.

@bob you're missing the crucial concept of what infinite time and resources means.

How so? Does it imply infinite cognitive resources? If so then yes I agree that I misunderstood the XKCD.

My general thought process is that even with infinite paper (e.g.) on which to take notes and infinite time to think and write, if my human brain is as it is today, that’s not sufficient for me to understand and reason about systems of unlimited complexity—there will be some complexity level beyond which my finite human brain will be unable to comprehend even given unlimited time and “whiteboarding space”. But if resources includes my cognitive abilities—a super charged brain, then yes it would suffice to understand any system. Are cognitive abilities considered a resource here?

The simulation hypothesis doesn't seem to be justified (it's a claim with no explanatory or predictive power), so that puts the question of the computational complexity of a simulated universe to rest.
As for a non-simulated universe: As one example, you need to do an ungodly amount of maths to perfectly calculate the effects of multi-body gravitational forces for simulation. But in the real world, there is no such calculation. Each body exists as a distinct entity that bends spacetime to influence the bodies around it. It's something that's actually happening, not something where you have to simulate every interaction between all bodies.
One might ask what's the ultimate foundational "stuff" that the universe is made of, that makes all of this work... but I don't know if that question even makes sense, never mind anyone actually having the answer. We know about atoms and spacetime and quantum fields and stuff, and that's about the deepest that our knowledge goes.
Those things work the way they do, and that's about all we can say at this point. We'd just be speculating about anything "below" that. Maybe in future our knowledge would go deeper, but then that might just push the question down to whatever the things further down are.

To me, the Simulation "Hypothesis" looks a heck of a lot like "deism for atheists".

I actually agree with Lowri on this one, but I'll play Devil's advocate and argue the 'simulationist' viewpoint for fun.
If you were going to create a simulated universe on a computer, would the 'people' in the simulated environment have enough computational power (within the simulation) to replicate the universe that they exist in?  I think it's obvious that they cannot because that would mean they have as much computational power as what it takes to create their own universe. So you say, OK, I'll provide them with that. But now, they simulate another universe within theirs. You need at least 3 times what you started with. And then that simulation within a simulation creates another universe. You should see where this is going: infinite computing power.  So, it should not be surprising for the occupants of a simulated universe to wonder at the computing power required to create their own universe.
Again, I don't really believe any of this, but I think it's fun to discuss.
I do want to recommend a book that I consider highly underrated: The Planiverse by a A.K. Dewdney.  It made me consider how our universe might appear to a 4-dimensional (spatial) being.

If you are alone, watching a simulation of our reality (similar to Grand Theft Auto
Video game series). Then you don't have to go crazy, one Sony PlayStation is enough.

While the people in the university may (debatably) not have the external compputational power, they pretty much could have WAY better algorithms. Well, it is not that I pretend we do have these.

Ah, the old tyranny of the universe simulation equation

"I think it's obvious that they cannot because that would mean they have as much computational power as what it takes to create their own universe." while this could be true I don't think this is obvious. It is not clear that computational resources have to be limited / finite. There is no principle that says that a small region of an infinite universe doesn't have "enough" resources to simulate a similar infinite universe. Infinity can be counter intuitive. Think of how there are infinitely many real numbers in any interval of real numbers. (And the cardinality is also the same.)

@Kvothe "There is no principle that says that a small region of an infinite universe doesn't have "enough" resources to simulate a similar infinite universe." There is such a principle based on information theory. See here and here

@TheMatrixEquation-balance Video games like GTA are a perfect example of how hard it is to produce a simulacrum of our reality. I'm sure you've seen the 'clipping' of objects in such games. They are surface rendered. It's more like an old 'wild west' movie set where the store fronts have nothing behind them.

@Kvothe In our universe, information has mass-energy.  Literally.  The same system with information in it or not differs, and the one with more information has an increase in mass-energy.  The amount of information you can fit in a region of space is limited by the space's surface area, and information is not lost through physics, and information can only spread at the speed of light - so the total amount of information the universe can ever have is limited.  A small region our universe cannot have enough resources to simulate a similar infinite universe.

@Kvothe: There is a dilemma induced by asking whether a simulation inherits QM from its parent or has simulated QM. If the simulation's QM is inherited, then its inhabitants can do certain experiments with polynomial cost and the parents need exponential energy to assert control over them. If QM is simulated, then the parents must spend exponential resources on the simulation by Holevo's theorem. Either way, simulations with QM are exponentially expensive to administer, so there can't be very many of them.

@Corbin Interesting argument. I've seen claims that QM is proof that we live in a simulation (not convinced.)  More to ponder...

@JimmyJames, already in our universe things are not as clear cut as you make them seem. And we know next to nothing about any physics outside a potential simulation (except that it is capable of running our universe as simulation which is some information at least). Also the stack exchange answer you link is highly deceptive. It is asking where certain numbers come from and that is explained in the answers. Because it doesn't ask the actual question on whether there is a bound on the information in the answers do not go into detail that these are very hand-wavy arguments based on naturalness.

@Kvothe What basis do you have to propose that infinite information can be stored in a finite amount of space?

@Jimmy. We really don't know. And that is all I'm saying. We don't know whether there is some smallest unit such as a Planck length bit. Of course our approximate theories tend to have smallest units but that is by the very nature of being an approximate theories. Semi-classical gravity suggest there is such a thing as a Bekenstein bound and that all black holes are the same but we really don't know whether in a fundamental theory of quantum gravity this would be the case. And that is for our universe. For a hypothetical universe that would simulate us we really have no clue on the physics.

(Of course I meant black holes with the same M J Q etc quantum numbers being the same.)

@Kvothe You asserted there are no principles preventing this. I pointed you to at least one.  You don't have to believe in these principles, but they clearly exist. That is, you can imagine that maybe there's a way to measure things smaller than the Plank length but the principle that we cannot exists, and it is not my invention.

@JimmyJames, okay, I'm done discussing then. You pointed to an answer that asked where the number comes from and it explained it. Nothing about whether this number is very accurate or justified. I pointed out it's flaws. (I'm a professional High Energy Theorist by the way and I'm strongly suspecting you are not. So I don't think further discussion would be productive.)

@Kvothe I pointed you to two links with different principles and as a high energy theorist, you should be aware that there are many arguments for why this can't be possible. But when you have demonstrated that it is, please let me know.

The universe is not running an advanced simulation. The events and items in the universe are what it is. There is nothing for the universe to "pull off." It could not do otherwise.

So the universe is what it is as a matter of brute fact, there is no deeper explanation as to how it is able to run complex laws so smoothly. Is that what you are saying?

@user80226 the universe does not run any kind of law whether simple or complex. What you think of as "laws" are a summary description from human observation.

@WeatherVane But philosophers of science find it interesting that the universe has regular patterns that we're able to summarize into laws. It's the whole "why is mathematics so effective in physics?" thing.

@Barmar I wan't disputing any of that, but pointing out that the laws are descriptive, not prescriptive.

@WeatherVane True, but if the laws "work", it's evidence that this is actually how the universe runs. It's hard to distinguish the two viewpoints, and scientists differ in how they view this.

In other words, are scientists reverse-engineering the universe, or just treating it as a black box?

@Barmar the universe ran quite happily before any of those so-called laws were formulated. It didn't need human help. The fact that some prove to be inexact and subject to improvement throws light on their nature, and nature really doesn't care what we say. It's a small step from "Science's Laws" to the hubris of "Our Laws... My laws" as if they personally take credit for it. Other attempts to describe the universe undergo profound changes in viewpoint, such as the shift from a geocentric description of the solar system to a heliocentric one. I am sure that other paradigm shifts will happen.


This makes me wonder: if simulating even a few atoms using the fundamental laws of quantum mechanics is computationally overwhelming, how does the universe manage to operate on such a vast scale?

Simple. It's massively parallel. If we had machines with the same degree of parallellism (plus data capacity), we could create a simulation that would run just as fast (keeping the same level of detail). The only machine for this that we currently have is the universe itself.
You seem to be forgetting that in each simulation the level of detail matters. There is a trade-off between speed and amount of data that can be processed (which is equivalent to level of detail generated).
(In our universe we are used to seeing a particular level of detail. No measurement has infinite precision. If it would suddenly turn out that all physical constants, when measured with much greater precision than now,
all ended with long strings of 0's, we should get a bit worried... But I'm sure that would then justify funding the SESI project, the Search for Extra Simulation Intelligence, exploring the outer fringes of the decimal expansion of π and trying to decipher any messages contained in those. Or course, philosophers always want to kick up some trouble, so we would get arguments saying that π, despite being transcendental, does not contain messages; we should look in e, which is far more likely to contain a hidden message since it's connected to "life" processes. The physicist will keep saying, however, that we should try to increase the precision of the measurements again, and see what we get. Perhaps the 0's will turn out to be a fluke.)
For an early exploration of how to make universe creating/simulating machines and how to become gods, see Stanislav Lem's hilarious book Summa Technologiae.

Actually, that is probably the key. The universe is the computronium.

And interestingly, the light speed threshold provides a certain degree of locality which is crucial for distributed computations (sharing data across the entire universe would break parallelism).

@Peter-ReinstateMonica - I had not thought of that... That's kind of scary :)

There's nothing scary about it; the universe is participatory and each particle has a modicum of indeterminism, that's all. Physics arises from the interaction of many particles in parallel. A computer is merely a stream of entropy that we are able to usefully decode.

This question assumes a privileged view of the time dimension of the universe, i.e. that the universe evolves over time in a causal, step-by-step fashion that mimics our perception of time and causality.
There are ways this premise could be false. Perhaps everything that ever happens, ever has happened, and ever will happen is simply one fixed solution to a system of equations. There is no change that needs simulation. We merely perceive different aspects of this reality at different times and places.

The simulation doesn't need to simulate the entire universe's gazillion particles, quantum mechanics, general relativity and all the bells and whistles. It only needs to simulate enough to convince the simulant referring to itself here as user80226 that it's real.
Relatively speaking it doesn't need to simulate much at all, it need not even simulate your local environment, just your mind and your perceptions.

So now 'simulation' amounts to 'brain in vat'. Ok. Might as well throw solipsism in for good measure.


In former times the favorite answer to your question “how does the
universe manage to operate on such a vast scale?” was the theistic
answer:

A divine intelligence operates the universe
or a divine intelligence created a universe with an intrinsic process    mechanism.


But this kind of answer does not rest on a sound philosophical
argument. Because the answer promps the subsequent question: Is there a a
divine intelligence and - if yes – how does it operate?
From the viewpoint of science the original question has no answer.
Possibly the question is ill-posed.



If you wanted to simulate how different object interact, you'd need to figure out what happens, you'd need to formalize that and ultimately you'd need to compute how every object interacts with every other object for each time step.
While if you just wanted to know how the real world objects interact, then all you'd have to do is: wait.
It's like the difference between describing what you see in it's full glory and actually seeing it. The latter literally takes a blink of an eye, the former could take years and fill tomes depending on the level of detail.
Or if you pick up a pen and draw random lines on a piece of paper that might take you a few minutes while if you gave that to experts and task them with recreating a perfect copy of that, down to the level of the atoms, that might take forever or not be possible at all.
So perfect replications or simulations are often a lot more difficult than just doing the real thing.
And with regards to computational complexity of simulation you might also take a look at how we deal with that already. So in order to save resources you could tune down the complexity. So rather than complex molecules and interactions between gazillions of particles you abstract idk entire planets to (x,y,z, weight) coordinates for example. So less fine grained resolution. Or you could localize the observation and only compute what is directly visible while treating the rest only as probability distribution if at all. Also obviously the "hardware" is outside of the universe so why should it be limited by the restrictions of the universe? Like our computers are like building turing machines inside of minecraft for example, they are rudimentary and lack power if you compare them to a modern gaming pc that is million times bigger and faster than trying to recreate that within a program.
So the computer running the universe (if such a thing exist) could have dimensions that vastly exceed the universe, that it is running. And it doesn't need to be just one computer, but each particle could be it's own computer in a network interacting with others directly or via a server or whatnot.
Though with regards to simulations and reality you would get into trouble with continuity. Like no matter how powerful your simulating machine is, if you zoomed closer and closer and closer at some point you'd see pixels or quanta of time because the the complexity of the universe scales with the number of particles and the resolution of interaction and that can get HUGE really quick. While if things don't get computed but just are and interact with each other directly and not computed by a central processing unit keeping track of everything, then this would be far less of a problem and would only require the universe itself and no additional hardware.

Incidentally, such a maximum resolution of reality appears to exist.

You have to remember that all computers we have built are a very tiny part of the universe, a very tiny part of the galactic cluster where we are, a very tiny part of the galaxy, a very tiny part of the solar system, a very tiny part of one planet.
Consider this: the mass of our universe is 1053 kg. The electrical parts of a single computer (CPU, memory, flash storage chips) are few hundred grams. Sure, there are mechanical parts like cooling fins and case but they don't take part in the computation.
So our universe is more than 53 orders of magnitude bigger than a computer.
I don't find it surprising at all that a computer has trouble running physics simulations, since it's so small. You can't expect so tiny part of our universe to run useful simulations.
Another problem is that computers aren't quantum. Semiconductor physics is affected by quantum mechanics, but the quantum effects are not utilized in computations. If our universe is a simulation, it's almost likely running on something quantum.
When we'll finally have working quantum computers, we can see that a quantum computer can simulate something small, like predicting how certain medicines work chemically.
But if the weight of the computing parts (not the cooling parts) of a quantum computer are measured in kilograms, it's still true that our universe is 53 orders of magnitude bigger. So while a small quantum computer can simulate small quantum systems, you can't for example expect such a tiny part of our universe to simulate the entire universe.

+1 for several repetitions of "very tiny". We just need a planet-sized computer.

+1: for an interesting perspective.

this answer explains why it is not surprising that we can't simulate the whole universe, but the OP mentions that we can't simulate even a small handful of atoms, using computers made up of trillions of trillions of [... etc] atoms. By implication, even if we converted a large fraction of all the matter in the universe into computers, we'd still be able to simulate only a tiny fraction of it.

If we want to think of the universe as a computer, then we ought to think of it as a massive scale quantum computer. In other words, if we pour an acid solution into a base, then each atom in the acid, base, and solvent is a separate qubit, all resolving their superpositions in real time. If and when we create a quantum computer with an Avogadro's number of qubits (as opposed to the 1000 or so qubits our current machines max out at) then we'll start being able to simulate simple chemical interactions.

"we pour an acid solution into a base" - Then you would see the smoke. This is easy to render, even now, on your laptop. Why do you think a simulator has to simulate the atoms and molecules if you cannot see them anyway?

@TheMatrixEquation-balance: generally speaking, when we mix an acid with a base it produces water and salts. It may release enough heat to create some steam, but smoke would be unusual.  At any rate, while we can render an approximation of rising steam, and calculate the overall end-product of the reaction, trying to model the reaction at a fine scale (to see, say, the pattern or gradient of a reaction as the solutions mix) is beyond our current means.

@TheMatrixEquation-balance We have not discovered any laws of physics that privilege human observation. If the true laws do, you'd expect to find interesting effects at the boundaries – but we have results in CS that show it's impossible to draw those boundaries perfectly.


the universe essentially runs an advanced "simulation" of quantum mechanics, general relativity, and more—smoothly and seamlessly, without any apparent bugs.

The universe isn't hardware with the physics being software it runs. In no sense is the universe is a simulation. You've merely asserted the case without any argument for it. Materially speaking, the universe is its physics. There is no meaningful distinction between the two.
That software can simulate a part of the universe does not entail that the universe is a also a simulation. Another way of putting it is that a photograph of you is not you.

"In no sense is the universe is a simulation" [citation needed]

@JBentley: No citation needed for the bleeding obvious.

It's by no means obvious at all. Perhaps you've heard of the simulation hypothesis? It's been neither proven nor disproven, so any claim that "in no sense is the universe a simulation" is just pseudoscience, and there's no way you can possibly be that certain.

@JBentley "In no sense do apples exist" is also pseudoscience, by the same argument. You'll agree that this is an unusual use of the term "pseudoscience", I hope.

@wizzwizz4 I'm not sure how those are comparable, or what definition of pseudoscience you're adopting. We have strong evidence that apples exist and no evidence that they don't. By the scientific method, it would be reasonable to believe that they do exist, and unreasonable to believe that they don't. One is free to believe that they don't exist, but that wouldn't be a scientific belief; it would be more akin to faith. The simulation hypothesis on the other hand has no evidence either for or against it, so any conclusion which claims to be 100% certain either way is also not based on science.

@wizzwizz4 So yes, "in no sense do apples exist" is pseudoscience, and no, I don't agree that this is an unusual use of the term. It's pseudoscience because it forms a factual conclusion without application of the scientific method.

@JBentley We don't have strong evidence that apples exist, because no observations have refuted solipsism! Unless we agree that this standard is unreasonable. // Our best scientific models suggest that it's impossible to construct a simulation of the universe as we observe it, at the level of detail that we can observe it, within the universe as we observe it to behave, making "in no sense is the universe a simulation" a perfectly valid scientific conclusion unless you take a non-scientific metaphysical definition of "simulation".

@wizzwizz4 I think we're maybe disagreeing on some definitions. To me, the scientific method means using observation to support or refute a falsifiable hypothesis. Anytime we make a conclusion which isn't based on the scientific method, we're being pseudoscientific. So, "solipsism means that seeing apples isn't evidence of apples existing" is pseudoscientific because we've nullified the very axiom (observation) that the scientific method is based on.

Similarly, "it's impossible to construct a simulation of the universe within the universe" can indeed be a valid scientific conclusion because observations can support it. However, the moment we start extending that to "it's impossible to construct a simulation of the universe from some higher universe", we've now clearly breached the principles of the scientific method and moved into the pseudoscientific. The latter isn't based on observation at all, and it's probably not even a falsifiable hypothesis to begin with (although some tests have been proposed).

@JBentley The universe is the domain of science. Talking about "higher universes" is, by your definition, pseudoscientific.

@wizzwizz4 That's exactly my point! If talking about (or to be more precise, forming conclusions about) higher universes is pseudoscientific, then forming conclusions about what is and isn't impossible within such a higher universe (e.g. that it is impossible for a higher universe to simulate our universe) is, by definition, also pseudoscientific.

@JBentley I believe we have reached agreement. (Will delete this comment.)

"...without any apparent bugs."
I think this is a useful statement with which to tease apart what's happening.  When a computer program has a "bug", it means it's not working as intended.  Some unforeseen circumstances, maybe unpredicted inputs, maybe programmer error, maybe a mechanical fault in the computer's hardware, cause the program to work in way the user or programmer didn't intend.  But given a more thorough understanding of the state of the computer, nothing about the bug will be a mystery.
With this in mind, what would a "bug" in physics even be?  You'd need to know what the universe and physics were intended for to say some phenomenon in it is a bug.  You might propose instead that a "bug" in physics is when something breaks known physical laws, but this doesn't really work either.  It doesn't prove physics broke, it proves our model of physics was incomplete, and a more thorough understanding of reality would explain it fine.  There's a kind of "God of the gaps" thing going on here.

Maybe I should've used the word "glitch" instead, see https://www.reddit.com/r/gamedev/comments/qe4eqi/what_is_the_difference_between_a_bug_and_a_glitch/?rdt=48704

@user80226 I don't think it makes a difference.  A "glitch" would fall under the "mechanical fault" category I mentioned.  It's not a miraculous error, it's just unforeseen circumstances behaving exactly as you would have expected had you had perfect information.

Is there a kind of "God of gaps" going on here?

@user80226 The Matrix is actually exactly the kind of thing I'm talking about.  The deja vu cat is an example of a "bug" not meaning that physics is broken, but rather that there's more to it than we understand at the moment.

An emulation is a crutch, is walking with ice skates on concrete, is making a vegan omelette — the universe, by contrast, is running natively on bare metal. Have you ever emulated an 80 bit floating point division with integer-only hardware?
That's the difference, just much more fundamental (after all, both ints and floats are still binary numbers, that is, very similar!).
